# ReflectionTestUtils set field method

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, reflection, mockito

Is there a way to use ReflectionTestUtils to set the return value of a method inside a field that represents a class to a mocked value instead of mocking the entire field? I was trying .setField(), but that only seems to work for the entire field. If there isn't, what would be a good substitute? Example of what I mean below:

```
public class Example() {
    private ClassField field;
    
    public methodThatUsesField() {

        methodReturnType type = field.method(); // I was trying to call .setField() to change the field's method to a mocked value, but can't figure out how to do it
        ...
    }
}
```

The class that is called in the field is very complicated, but there is a very simple public method that acts as the root of the class, and I want to set that to a specific value. The class itself does not have a constructor, so I need a way to get around that.

This is a spring boot project written in Java, and I need to use ReflectionTestUtils to be able to pass an argument into Mockito mock

Comment: Is it safe to assume both `Example` and `ClassField` are Spring-Beans (e.g. annotated with @Service) and `ClassField` is injected into `Example`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Mockito.spy(field)` and inject spied field using `ReflectionTestUtils`. Something like this

```
@SpringBootTest
class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private Example example;

    @Autowired
    private ClassField field;

    @Test
    void testMethodThatUsesField() {
        ClassField spiedField = Mockito.spy(field);
        Mockito.when(spiedField.method()).thenReturn(methodReturnTypeValue);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(example, "field", spiedField);
        example.methodThatUsesField();
     // assertions
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@Spy` on field or `Mockito.spy(field)`. I understand my statement doesn't reflect in example but you can implement using either way and both of them works. I have tested example I posted above.